# Visual Studio losing functions

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I have been noticing, over the last few weeks, that my installation of VS2008 keeps losing items from menus. Eg: The "Advanced" sub menu from the "Edit" menu pull down is no longer there.

I am not making any changes to the application, I'm not installation anything, ever, and I never mess about with the options dialogs.

This morning, after leaving my machine on over the weekend, I have come in to discover that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> no longer works. This used to be on the afore-mentioned "Edit -> Advanced" menu, but still the key combo worked. Now, nothing.

What the hell is happening? More to the point- how do I fix/stop it?

Comment: Aahahhaha, sorry to laugh but that is one of the most unique and interesting problems I ever heard of!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really not sure why that would be happening, but to fix it, try the list below in order from a command prompt (running VS in between each to see if it fixed the issue).

Please note that these will reset your settings, so be sure to save them first (Tools » Import and Export Settings...). `devenv` is present in `\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE`.

1. `devenv /setup`
2. `devenv /resetsettings`
3. `devenv /resetuserdata`

If all else fails, you could always try repairing your installation :\